# ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

In my rails app I'm trying to create a system that will reward users with badges for various achievements

created a table 'user_badges'

migration:

```
class CreateUserBadges < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :user_badges do |t|

    t.references :user, foreign_key: true
    t.references :badge, foreign_key: true

    t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

model UserBadge:

```
class UserBadge < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :badge

end
```

модель Badge:

```
class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users, through: :user_badges
  has_many :user_badges
end
```

model User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  has_many :badges, through: :user_badges
  has_many :user_badges

  ...
end
```

when I try to add a badge to the user:

```
b = Badge.create(title: 'first')

User.last.badges << b
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many 
:through association 'User#badges' which goes through 
'User#user_badges' before the through association is defined.
```

also when I simply call:

```
User.last.badges
```

same error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many 
:through association 'User#badges' which goes through 
'User#user_badges' before the through association is defined.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Define `has_many` association first then add `through:` association

```
class UserBadge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :badge
end

class Badge < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_badges # has_many association comes first
  has_many :users, through: :user_badges #through association comes after
end


class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :user_badges
  has_many :badges, through: :user_badges
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 6):

Note, in case you mistakenly wrote first has_many 2 times, then it can reproduce this error too. E.g.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :user_badges
  has_many :badges, through: :user_badges
  ...
  has_many :user_badges
end

# => Leads to the error of ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'User#badges' which goes through 'User#user_badges' before the through association is defined.
```

Active Record should alert has_many being used two times IMHO...

Comment: IMHO, this would be better-suited as a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 2):

While migrating a rails app from 5.2 to 6 I faced this error but in my case the relationships order was correct:

```
has_many :users_roles
has_many :roles,      :through => :users_roles
```

`[ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many :through association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49450963/activerecordhasmanythroughordererror-cannot-have-a-has-many-through-associat)`

The app uses `rolify` and it was at the top of the class:

I had to change the order:

```
has_many :users_roles
----------
rolify
----------
has_many :roles,      :through => :users_roles
```